# The following assertion was thrown building SpinKitCircle(state: _SpinKitCircleState#590ee(ticker active)): No Directionality widget found

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to test out the spin kit dependency for flutter but whenever I run the loading class it throws an error telling me that there might be a text misaligned but I am not using a text? Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Loading();
      },
    );
  }
}


class Loading extends StatelessWidget {
  const Loading({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.brown[100],
        child: const Center(
            child: SpinKitCircle(
              color: Colors.brown,
              size: 50.0,
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're not using a `MaterialApp` or `CupertinoApp` widget as a starting point you're going to have to declare the directionality yourself, for example by wrapping it in an `Directionality` widget:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.brown[100],
            child: const Center(
                child: SpinKitCircle(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    size: 50.0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

but I would advice you to just wrap the root of your project with an `MaterialApp` widget

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Loading();
          },
       ),
    );
  }
}
```